# Partially initializing object attributes using functools.partial in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, functools

I'm wondering whether it is a valid use case of [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to partially initialize object attributes in python. Let's say I have some base class `A` that has three object-level attributes (`attr1`, `attr2`, `attr3`):

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2, attr3):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2
        self.attr3 = attr3
        
    def do_something(self):
        pass
```

Now I want to create objects based on this base class for which one of the attributes (say `attr1`) is always fixed, but the other two may vary. One way I can think of doing this is to define a class that inherits from base class `A` and has a fixed class-level attribute which is used during initialization, something like this:

```py
class PartialA(A):
    attr1="foo" # fixed class-level attribute
    
    def __init__(self, attr2, attr3):
        super().__init__(self.attr1, attr2, attr3)
```

I can then create objects by specifying only the varying object-level attributes, like so:

```py
partial_a = PartialA(attr2="baz", attr3="baz")
```

Another way to achieve a similar behavior would be to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to partially initialize the `__init__` of the base class `A` and then create objects off of it:

```py
from functools import partial

PartialA = partial(A, attr1="foo")

partial_a = PartialA(attr2="bar", attr3="baz")
```

Are both approaches equally valid, or are there dangers/drawbacks to the approach using `functools.partial` in this way that I am currently not aware of? Would be happy to hear your opinions!

I tried both of the approaches outlined above and so far, I can not really see any difference in terms of behavior. But there might well be some reasons to favor one over another that I'm currently unaware of.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. I think this is too open-ended to give a conclusive answer. Like for example, have you considered that you can change the value of `PartialA.attr1` on the class? To me, that makes that method confusing, but it might be different to you. I'd prefer the `partial` personally, though it might depend how you're going to use it. You could even consider writing a function like `def partial_a(attr2, attr3, attr1="foo"): return A(attr1, attr2, attr3)`, or using an alternate constructor like in chepner's answer.

Comment: Also, "partial initialization" is a misnomer here, because you're not really initializing anything until `PartialA` is called. Really, `PartialA` is a [*factory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)) for `A`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I do realize that the question is quite open-ended. I wasn't quite sure how to put it more concrete and it is also really the comments and insights of more experienced people I am after. Also I wasn't aware of the term "factory", so sorry about the misnomer.

Comment: No need to apologize :) I didn't mean it as a correction, more to let you know what terms to look for in your own research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases, you are basically defining factory functions to create instances of `A`. I would take a third route, an alternate constructor implemented using a class method.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2, attr3):
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = attr2
        self.attr3 = attr3

    @classmethod
    def with_foo(cls, attr2, attr3):
        return cls("foo", attr2, attr3)
        
    def do_something(self):
        pass

a = A.with_foo("bar", "baz")  # a = A("foo", "bar", "baz")
```

One major difference between this and your two attempts is that you can't override how `A.with_foo` sets the first attribute. (With the class, you can simply redefine `PartialA.attr1` before creating an instance, plus you now have a weird second class that doesn't need to exist. With `partial`, you can still pass your own value of `attr1` as a keyword argument.)

Comment: Thanks! That's an interesting alternative approach and your reasoning mostly makes sense to me. However, I don't understand the last part: "With partial, you can still pass your own value of attr1 as a keyword argument". How exactly do you mean this? If I also specify `attr1` as a kwarg in the `PartialA` call using `functool.partial`  (i.e. my second approach), this raises a `TypeError`, as multiple values for `attr1` are passed.

Comment: It shouldn't; `PartialA(attr1=1, attr2=2, attr3=3)`, for example, should work fine. This is one of the benefits of using `partial` over a function wrapper.

Comment: You're right, my bad. `TypeError` only occurs if either only `attr2` or `attr2` and `attr3` are passed as positional arguments.

Comment: Right; positional arguments are always applied from left to right, regardless of whatever keyword arguments may have been supplied to the initial call to `partial`.